# Ошибка с типом переменной C# + PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, ado.net

Кратко введу в курс дела. Есть приложение на С# для работы с БД (PostgreSQl). Есть база данных, в которой есть таблица со списком детей, учащихся в школе:

```
create table child (
    id_child serial primary key, 
    FIO_child text not null,
    birthday date not null
);
```

Есть процедура, которая заполняет эту таблицу:

```
create or replace function insert_child (_fio_child text, _birthday date)
returns void as $$
begin 
    insert into child (fio_child, birthday) 
    values (_fio_child, _birthday);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Пытаясь запустить эту функцию через приложение на C# выдаёт ошибку:

> процедура insert_child(text, timestamp without time zone) не существует

Функция на С#:

```
public bool insert_child(string fio_child, DateTime birthday)
{
    bool saved = false;
    using(var cn = GetConnection())
    {
        cn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("call insert_child (:_fio_child, :_birthday);", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_fio_child", DbType.String).Value = fio_child;
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_birthday", DbType.DateTime).Value = birthday;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_birthday", DbType.Date).Value = birthday;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        // cn.Open();
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        saved = result == 1;
    }
    return saved;
}
```

Как я понял - ошибка тут `public bool insert_child(string fio_child, DateTime birthday)`, но  с её исправлением возникают сложности.

Comment: Неправильно поняли. Назовите функцию и процедуру разными именами и попробуйте ещё раз - там увидите, где ошибка

Comment: `AddWithValue` замените на `Add`.

Comment: @tym32167 Не существует процедуры в самой БД? Или я как-то неправильно к ней обращаюсь?

Comment: @aepot заменил. Не помогло.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение используя приведение типов (cast):

```
string sql = "select * from insert_child (@fio_child, cast(@birthday as date))";
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fio_child", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = fio_child;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = birthday;

int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Не используйте `AddWithValue`! Вторым параметром в этом методе идёт **значение**, а **не тип**. В этом суть вашей проблемы. Поставил минус.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert_child", cn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("_fio_child", NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = fio_child;
cmd.Parameters.Add("_birthday", NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = birthday;

int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Решение используя приведение типов (cast):
> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday",
> NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = birthday;

Решение работает! Сам промучался пол-дня, после обновления NuGet Npgsql 7.0.6

Comment: пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Когда ваша [репутация](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными